# JPA 2.0 - Oracle function using @NamedNativeQuery - Error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa-2.0

In JPA 2.0, I trying to call a Oracle function which returns a SYSREF CURSOR and takes one input parameter (ID).

Requirement: If the input parameter has a ID value if should fetch that record, if the input value is null it should return all data.

It works fine if I pass the input param (ID), but if I pass null value to input I get this error.

It works fine on JDBC, I am not sure if I a missing JPA syntax somewhere...

**Error:**

```
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_ENTITIES'
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**Entity**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ENTITIES")
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "getEntities", query = "{ ? = call pkg_entities.get_entities(:IN_ENTITY_ID)}", resultClass = Eentity.class, hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
```

**Repository**

```
    @Primary
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class EntityRepositoryJpa20Impl implements EntityRepository {

        @PersistenceContext
        EntityManager entityManager;

        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        @Override
        public List<Eentity> getEntities(String id) {
            Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getEntities");
            query.setParameter("IN_ENTITY_ID", id);
            return query.getResultList();
        }

    }
```

**Test**

```
    @Test
    public void testNotWorking() {
        List<Eentity> entities = entityRepository.getEntities(null);
    }   


    @Test
    public void testWorksFine() {
        List<Eentity> entities = entityRepository.getEntities("900001");
    }
```

**Oracle function**

```
    function get_entities(in_entity_id number) return sys_refcursor
    is
      v_cursor sys_refcursor;
    begin
      open v_cursor for
      select
        entity_id,
        b,
        c
      from entities e
      where e.entity_id = nvl(in_entity_id,e.entity_id)
      and e.is_excluded = 'N'
      order by e.entity_id;
      return v_cursor;
    end get_entities;
```

**UPDATE:-**

If I pass empty string ("") it worked fine but did not work when I pass null. 
I now created two Java methods one for each as below,

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ENTITIES")
    @NamedNativeQueries(value = {
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "getEntity", query = "{ ? = call pkg_entities.get_entities(:IN_ENTITY_ID)}", resultClass = Eentity.class, hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") }),
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "getEntities", query = "{ ? = call pkg_entities.get_entities()}", resultClass = Eentity.class, hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") }) })
    public class Eentity implements Serializable {
```

Comment: can you provide your oracle package body, get_entities method

Comment: @sgpalit Thanks oracle function added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to modify your PL/SQL package by adding a default parameter value:

```
IN_ENTITY_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
```

i.e. in your case:

```
function get_entities(in_entity_id number default null) return sys_refcursor
```

Answer (score 1):

`DEFAULT NULL` try adding this to your input parameter